# In / From correct usage with "look"

Tags: prepositions

What is the correct form of the following ?

> Look that **from** your own eyes ?

OR

> Look that **in** your own eyes ?

Comment: Might I suggest "See with your own eyes" or "Look at that *with* your own eyes". The only time you would use the words "in" or "from" (at least from my limited knowledge) would be like: "The sparkle from my eyes..." or "The sparkle in my eyes..." But I would not be **looking** or **seeing** things *in/from* my eyes. FWIW

Comment: You cannot say that you "have a doubt", when you are not sure about something, because "doubt" means "disbelief". You can say "I have a question.".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When used to talk about using your eyes, "look" is intransitive, meaning that it does not accept an object. You cannot say "he looks the apple". Instead you need to say that "he looks at the apple", where "at the apple" specifies the direction of looking.

Similarly, you have to say "Look at that with your own eyes.", where "with your own eyes" specifies the manner of looking. Also, if the object is near, you should say "Look at it with your own eyes.", because "that" tends to connote something not so near.

Answer (score 0):

I would say "Have a look at it for yourself". "With your own eyes"  sounds like an expression of a foreign language, but it doesn't sound English.